# Force.com IDE still in v38.0?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, eclipse, force.com-ide, api-version

I am trying to update eclipse force.com IDE so that I can create lightning components with v41.0(with Winter 18 release feature). I do not see an update available and while creating the component/apex class etc I get an option for v38.0. I do a work around to change the xml file manually but would be great to create the components with v41.0 initially.

When installing force.com IDE I used the link - https://developer.salesforce.com/media/force-ide/eclipse45 . Reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there's been a major push for Lightning, there's been a major lag with the Force.com IDE. You could [fork the core](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore) and add 41.0 support, or even get on the dev branch if you wanted to get a peek at the upcoming version, or you might try the [Force.com IDE 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_ide2.meta/sfdx_ide2/sfdx_ide2_get_started_download_install.htm), which supports DX, meaning that you can naturally create v41 items, because DX provides the actual file-creation, so it can be up-to-date faster than the classic IDE.

Unfortunately, Force.com IDE 2 seems a bit too "beta" for most people's liking, so your mileage may vary. You might instead consider creating your code directly the Force.com Developer Console, and then pulling the source down to your IDE. The Develper Console has traditionally been the first to be updated ahead of all other IDEs (even DX), and since DX is intended to be used this way (develop in your org and then pull to your repo), this might be the best way to create your components in the latest version by default.

Comment: Great insights. I was wondering where I could find the details about the next api version release. I saw - https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/wiki/Contributing-Code but I might have to explore more to see where I can find details about upcoming versions.

Comment: Is it realistic to assume that the Force.com IDE (not IDE 2) will ever be updated to V41?

Comment: I found this in issue list- https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/225. @cropredy

Comment: @cropredy With precious few exceptions, features to be discontinued are announced in advance. I would say that, since no such announcement has been published, the Force.com IDE will eventually make it to at least v41, unless Force.com IDE 2 completely displaces Force.com IDE. As long as we're using the classic IDE, Salesforce should keep updating it. Once it gets down to a point where nobody's using it (say, less than 10% or something like that), they'll stop updating it.

Comment: Which IDE do you guys use if I may ask.

Comment: @SfdcBat At home, Cloud9 or Developer Console. At work, Force.com IDE or Developer Console. However, once we go DX, we are likely moving to VS Code as our new standard IDE.

Comment: @sfdcbat at work - Force.com IDE but very impressed at DF 17 w/ Intellicloud V2 (not yet released) - a plugin for IntelliJ

Comment: A purely personal opinion but I've been consistently impressed with illuminated cloud and highly recommend it as an IDE.